# Install windows 10 on bootcamp fails

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, partition

Im trying to install windows 10 with bootcamp.
But what i`m trying it wil not work. I hope some one can help me.
When i create a bootable USB via bootcamp this all works wel.
than i delete the Bootcamp partition manually and create a new one (same size) and select the format option **Free Space** 
When i restart the MBP with the **option** button hold i see the EFI USB drive.
When i start the installation process the, it is asking a few questions about the language and key, . also it is asking on which drive windows should be installed. I select the free space part and format it. Only then the **next** button lits-up. The install continues. When finalizing the installation im receiving an error **Windows could not update the computer's boot configuration**  I have no clue why this is happening.

Does anyone have the same problem?
Hope someone can help me, thank in advanced

OSx version 10.10.5

MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)

Windows 10 pro x64 (ISO form MS site)

Supported sites:

[How to Install Windows 8.1 on Haswell Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112435/how-to-install-windows-8-1-on-haswell-mac)

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6522350

http://www.123myit.com/2014/08/fix-gpt-error-windows-installed-disk/

[Bootcamp - No ISO Option](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170759/bootcamp-no-iso-option)

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Applications` - `Utilities` click `Boot Camp Assistant` follow the step by step instructions

- Format the partitioned drive first
- Give the partition at least 40GBs
- Make sure you have a valid copy of windows

If you need more help here are a couple of videos with step by step instructions:

- [How to Install windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShdKIMA7gz0)
- [Make a Bootable USB_Drive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9w3sFsiaA0)

Answer (score 0):

(I cannot add comments due to missing points)

I am pretty sure, as soon as Windows 10 starts to boot on UEFI, things mess up. I tried a lot with an unsupported MBA 2011 and never saw such strange behaviour.

If you are able to skip the boot config error:

log in, DIRECTLY install boot camp software without reboot (like the unattended way from BCA). Once you can start the Bootcamp tool, you are able to select the boot partition an this apple tool seems to be able to edit the BCD in the UEFI Firmware correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So back in the day (2014) I had an issue that sounds similar installing Windows 7. The underlying cause was my USB 3 thumb drive that I was using as the Windows install disk. I wrote about it here:
https://deciphertools.com/blog/2014_08_09_bootcamp_unable_to_create_new_system_partition/ (the "Setup was Unable to Create a New System Partition" for Windows 7 sounds vaguely in the realm of your "Windows could not update the computer's boot configuration")

Curious if using a USB dvd drive or USB 2.0 thumb drive still fixes this problem. According to this page from Apple (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990) it looks promising.